# Как сделать асинхронный IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, tpl

Делаю поиск, по нескольким сразу местам.

На вернем уровне пока что-то типа:

```
  foreach (var item in Plugins.SelectMany(p => p.Search(query)))
    Items.Add(new ViewModel(item));
```

А в каждой реализации метода Search:

```
public override IEnumerable<Item> Search(string name)
{
  await some resource
  foreach (var element in networkResult)
    ...
    yield return result;
}
```

На деле, хочу параллельный доступ ко всем поискам, чтобы каждый элемент появлялся в UI когда он готов, а не когда закончится всё целиком, как это сейчас работает. Что именно тут в таски оборачивать - нету хороших идей. Снаружи вроде логичнее выглядит `Task<IEnumerable>`, но реализовывать как правильно - не понимаю.

Comment: Зачем здесь вообще перечисление? Добавляйте результаты в нужную вам коллекцию прямо внутри асинхронной функции

Comment: @tym32167 с точки зрения прикладной - поиск возвращает результаты, а что с ними делает клиент - другое дело.

Comment: На текущий момент — только вручную. В следующей версии фреймворка появится `IAsyncEnumerable`, с ним будет проще.

Comment: @VladD а посмотреть где то можно, как это вручную сделать? У меня пока получается франкенштейн =_=

Comment: Ну, чтобы не делать всё вручную, есть IX (https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/tree/develop/Ix.NET/Source/System.Interactive.Async). Ну или вот ещё нашёл (https://github.com/tyrotoxin/AsyncEnumerable), про это не уверен.

Comment: @VladD что-то не понял я, как этим IAsyncEnumerator пользоваться. Всмысле, использовать то его очевидно как, а вот создать - что-то не очень.

Comment: @Monk: Я напишу пример немного позже.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Смотрите, это не так сложно.

Вы устанавливаете Ix, nuget-пакеты `System.Interactive` и `System.Interactive.Async`. У вас появляется интерфейс `IAsyncEnumerable` и вспомогательные классы.

Пользоваться можно вот так:

```
static class FileEx
{
    public static IAsyncEnumerable<string> ReadLinesAsync(string path)
    {
        // IAsyncEnumerable<T> обладает только одной функцией - создать энумератор
        return AsyncEnumerable.CreateEnumerable(() =>
        {
            var stream = File.OpenText(path);
            string current = null;
            // создаём энумератор при помощи готовой фабрики
            return AsyncEnumerable.CreateEnumerator(
                // у StreamReader.ReadLineAsync нет перегрузки с ct, пичалько
                moveNext: async ct => (current = await stream.ReadLineAsync()) != null,
                current: () => current,
                dispose: stream.Dispose);
        });
    }
}
```

Смотрите, что тут происходит. Для начала, одна и та же последовательность может пробегаться разными кусками кода вперемежку, поэтому состояние текущего обхода мы держим в энумераторе. В принципе, нам нужно было бы завести отдельный класс для энумератора, и держать в нём свойства. Но мы пойдём более модным путём, и будем держать данные в замыкании. Мы открываем `StreamReader`, заводим переменную для текущей строки.

Асинхронная функция `MoveNext` итератора получает следующую строку из `StreamReader`'а, и проверяет результат на `null` (`null` означает конец файла). Функция `Current` просто выдаёт текущую строку. А функция `Dispose` закрывает в конце поток.

Теперь с этим можно работать:

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var lines = FileEx.ReadLinesAsync("text.txt");
        using (var en = lines.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (await en.MoveNext())
                Console.WriteLine(en.Current);
        }
    }
}
```

Или просто

```
await FileEx.ReadLinesAsync("text.txt")
            .ForEachAsync(s => Console.WriteLine(s));
```

---

В следующей версии C# планируется [поддержка асинхронных энумераторов](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/async-streams.md) прямо в языке. С ней наш пример запишется так:

```
static class FileEx
{
    public static async IAsyncEnumerable<string> ReadLinesAsync(string path)
    {
        using (var stream = File.OpenText(path))
        {
            string current;
            while ((current = await stream.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
                yield return current;
        };
    }
}

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach await (var s in FileEx.ReadLinesAsync("text.txt"))
            Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

---

Смотрите, для конкретно вашего случая ([вот такой код](https://github.com/MonkAlex/MangaReader/blob/998d18256fac659be985da4ea96080e02baefc6d/Sites/Acomics.ru/Parser.cs#L205)) вам стоит разобрать задачу на составные части, поскольку асинхронных штук в ней много. 
Потом можно будет связать их вместо.

Начнём с получения страниц и их разбора. Список хостов получить просто, тут не нужна асинхронность:

```
var hosts = ConfigStorage.Plugins
    .Where(p => p.GetParser().GetType() == typeof(Parser))
    .Select(p => p.GetSettings().MainUri);
```

Теперь, нам нужно по хосту получить список `HtmlNodeCollection`. Это «длинная» задача, выносим её в таск:

```
async Task<HtmlNodeCollection> GetHostMangasAsync(string name, Uri host, CookieClient client)
{
    var searchHost = new Uri(host, "search?q=" + WebUtility.UrlEncode(name));
    var page = await Task.Run(() => Page.GetPage(searchHost, client));
    if (!page.HasContent)
        return null;

    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var document = new HtmlDocument();
        document.LoadHtml(page.Content);
        return document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='tile col-sm-6']");
    });
}
```

Теперь, нам нужно из неасинхронной последовательности host'ов и `Task`'а, который получает из каждого хоста `HtmlNodeCollection`, получить асинхронную последовательность. Такого метода в Ix из коробки я не нашёл, но его легко сколотить самому. Сделаем его обобщённым, вдруг ещё понадобится. Код практически ничем не отличается от примера с `File.ReadLinesAsync`.

```
static class AsyncEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IAsyncEnumerable<R> SelectAsync<T, R>(
        this IEnumerable<T> seq, Func<T, Task<R>> selector)
    {
        return AsyncEnumerable.CreateEnumerable(() =>
        {
            IEnumerator<T> seqEnum = seq.GetEnumerator();
            R current = default;
            return AsyncEnumerable.CreateEnumerator(
                moveNext: async ct =>
                {
                    if (!seqEnum.MoveNext())
                        return false;
                    current = await selector(seqEnum.Current);
                    return true;
                },
                current: () => current,
                dispose: seqEnum.Dispose);
        });
    }
}
```

Вооружившись этим, мы можем написать такое:

```
IAsyncEnumerable<HtmlNodeCollection> GetSearchPages(string name)
{
    var hosts = ConfigStorage.Plugins
        .Where(p => p.GetParser().GetType() == typeof(Parser))
        .Select(p => p.GetSettings().MainUri);
    var client = new CookieClient();
    return hosts.SelectAsync(host => GetHostMangasAsync(name, host, client)))
                .Where(nc => nc != null);
}
```

Проверка на `null` нужна, потому что `GetHostMangasAsync` может вернуть `null`.

Отлично, переходим дальше. Итак, у нас снова есть неасинхронная коллекция `HtmlNodeCollection`, из каждого элемента которой мы может вытащить при помощи асинхронной функции (т. к. у нас есть обращение к сети) экземпляр `IManga`. Пишем код:

```
async Task<IManga> GetMangaFromNode(Uri host, CookieClient client, HtmlNode manga)
{
    // Это переводчик, идем дальше.
    if (manga.SelectSingleNode(".//i[@class='fa fa-user text-info']") != null)
        return null;

    var image = manga.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='img']//a//img");
    var imageUri = image?.Attributes.Single(a => a.Name == "data-original").Value;

    var mangaNode = manga.SelectSingleNode(".//h3//a");
    var mangaUri = mangaNode.Attributes.Single(a => a.Name == "href").Value;
    var mangaName = mangaNode.Attributes.Single(a => a.Name == "title").Value;

    if (!Uri.TryCreate(mangaUri, UriKind.Relative, out Uri test))
        return null;

    var result = Mangas.Create(new Uri(host, mangaUri));
    result.Name = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(mangaName);
    if (imageUri != null)
        result.Cover = await client.DownloadDataAsync(imageUri);
    return result;
}
```

Нам нужно теперь их соединить. Это несложно. Единственная проблема — в `GetMangaFromNode` тоже нужен `CookieClient`, а у нас от спрятан внутри `GetSearchPages`. Окей, будем передавать его снаружи. Затем, у нас из `GetSearchPages` возвращается только `HtmlNodeCollection`, а нужен ещё и `host`. Модифицируем `GetSearchPages`: будем возвращать пары из хоста и коллекции `HtmlNode`, и принимать на вход `CookieClient`:

```
IAsyncEnumerable<(Uri host, HtmlNodeCollection nodes)> GetSearchPages(
        string name, CookieClient client)
{
    var hosts = ConfigStorage.Plugins
        .Where(p => p.GetParser().GetType() == typeof(Parser))
        .Select(p => p.GetSettings().MainUri);
    return
        hosts.SelectAsync(
                async host => (host, nodes: await GetHostMangasAsync(name, host, client)))
             .Where(pair => pair.nodes != null);
}
```

Ну и комбинируем. У нас каждая синхронная коллекция `HtmlNode` при помощи асинхронной функции даёт коллекцию экземпляров `IManga`. Это делается снова при помощи нашего `SelectAsync`:

```
IAsyncEnumerable<IManga> GetFromHostAndNodes(
        Uri host, HtmlNodeCollection nodes, CookieClient client) =>
    nodes.SelectAsync(node => GetMangaFromNode(host, client, node));
```

Теперь можно складывать паззл:

```
public IAsyncEnumerable<IManga> Search(string name)
{
    var client = new CookieClient();
    return
        GetSearchPages(name, client)
            .SelectMany(pair => GetFromHostAndNodes(pair.host, pair.nodes, client))
            .Where(m => m != null);
}
```

Всё!

Comment: А где централизованно можно прочитать про все новые нововведения в будущей редакции языка?

Comment: @iluxa1810: Ну, никаких гарантий насчёт новых фич нет. Информация появляется [здесь](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang) и [здесь](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/Language%20Feature%20Status.md), а также [здесь](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/) и [здесь](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/). Но централизованной информации нет, приходится вылавливать по чуть-чуть.

Comment: Перечитал и попробовал сам. К сожалению, код который вы привели мне не сильно помогает, но тут я сам виноват, вопрос плохо описал. Суть в чём - в синхронном коде есть yield return, который прерывает выполнение, по аналогии с этим прерыванием хочется чтобы работал `IAsyncEnumerable`. А так - пришлось делать аналог `File.Open`, который подготовит все данные вполне синхронно, а потом уже отдельным методом типа `ReadLineAsync` дополнять данные тяжелыми запросами по необходимости. Фактически, такое можно было сделать и без всяких сторонних библиотек, или я чего не понимаю?

Comment: @Monk: Ну да, то, чтобы работало вместе yield и await, не так просто, и будет доступно как раз в следующей версии языка (смотрите код снизу). В моём примере File.Open синхронный, но он лёгкий, а тяжёлые куски — `ReadLineAsync`, они обращаются к файловой системе. Фактически можно было бы сделать и без библиотек, ну так всё можно сделать вручную. Асинхронность действий лежит всё равно на вас.

Comment: @Monk: Вы лучше покажите, какой у вас есть код, и что вам хотелось бы примерно получить.

Comment: https://github.com/MonkAlex/MangaReader/commit/a99ff7d37f48451021d21c397e5e692d0170442c?diff=split#diff-513ba26399e907fa375acfa0f022c738L205
У меня примерно вот так получилось, в целом работает как ожидал - поиск начал по элементу с разных источников закидывать.

Comment: @Monk: Хм, смотрите. У вас бОльшая часть работы идёт до самой энумерации. Это не очень хорошо. Есть два пути: (1) сделать функцию `Search` асинхронной тоже, чтобы не блокировать поток, и (2) перенести работу в энумератор. Я попробую посмотреть и предложить улучшения немного позже.

Comment: @Monk: Ага, кажется, разобрался. Сейчас дополню ответ.

Comment: @Monk: Дополнил, разбирайтесь :)

Comment: Вчера вечером не дождался итогового варианта, так что сегодня вечером буду пробовать. Выглядит хорошо и вроде логично, спасибо.

Comment: @Monk: Пожалуйста! Надеюсь, поможет.

Comment: Таки завелось, насчет стало ли быстрее например - не мерял, шустро шевелится. Если я правильно понял, главная идея - заменить каждый синхронный foreach на SelectAsync?

Comment: @Monk: Угу, именно так. Плюс идея ещё в том, чтобы не делать большой кусок, а разложить на маленькие IAsyncEnumerable'ы и скомбинировать их